# Var doesn't get elements from document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, html

```
var index=1;
showPics(index);


function showPics(n) {
    var i;
    var j = document.getElementsByClassName("gpic");
    if (n > j.length) {index = 1;}
    if (n < 1) {
        index = x.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    j[index-1].style.display = "block";
}

function showNext(x) {
    showPics(index += x);
}
```

At the document.getElementsByClassName() part somehow "j" doesn't get the elements.
[as you can see there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwk9x.png) . This is the html part of the problem:

```
<div position="relative" img=bigimg>
    <button position="absolute" id=leftbtn onclick="showNext(-1);"></button>
        <img class="gpic" src='../images/0.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/1.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/2.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src = '../images/3.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/4.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/5.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/6.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/7.jpg'>
        <img class="gpic" src ='../images/8.jpg'>
<button position="absolute" id=rightbtn onclick="showNext(1);"></button>
```

I don't know what causes the problem.
I just trying to do something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

Comment: Do you make sure the script is at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Are those buttons in a form? If so, the surprising default `type` is getting you: They *submit* the form.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @Matthew: Er...there is that. :-) It would still be fine when clicked, though, if it weren't for the magic `x`.

Comment: What's `x`? (The one in `x[i].style.display = "none";`, not the other one.) Where is it declared, and where is it filled in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Are you stopping the debugger right then when `j` gets assigned?

Comment: Simple typo, You use it right after the loop and wrong inside the loop. Another issue could be where you have the script location. If it is in the head, it ain't going to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the variable `x` needing to be `j`, your code seems to work as intended.  You also try to set an attribute `position` on a tag, and this is not doing what you intend.  You either need to have the `style` attribute set `<div style="position: relative">`, or in CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, in your code, there is no closing `</div>` tag.

```js
var index = 1;
showPics(index);

function showPics(n) {
  var i;
  var j = document.getElementsByClassName("gpic");
  if (n > j.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    index = j.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    j[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  j[index - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function showNext(x) {
  showPics(index += x);
}
```

```css
img {
  margin: 0 auto
}

#leftbtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

#rightbtn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id=leftbtn onclick="showNext(-1);">Prevoius</button>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/340x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/330x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/320x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/310x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/290x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/280x150'>
  <img class="gpic" src='http://via.placeholder.com/270x150'>
  <button id=rightbtn onclick="showNext(1);">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Actually the div has a closing, sorry I did not mentioned it. The problem was with that silly positioning. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript should look like that:

```
var index=1;
showPics(index);

function showPics(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("gpic");
    if (n > x.length) {index = 1;}
    if (n < 1) {
        index = x.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[index-1].style.display = "block";
}

function showNext(x) {
    showPics(index += x);
}
```

There is was issue with declaring variable j instead of x as rest of your code suggest.